# Word or phrase for when you're hungry but nothing sounds good to eat

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'd guess almost everyone knows this feeling: you're hungry but nothing sounds good to eat.  I don't think there is a commonly known word or phrase, but anyone know of a word or phrase that has been coined to describe such a situation?

P.S. I'm gonna try to get this one going... "I'm feeling picky."
Just thought I'd do my research first :)

Comment: I'd say you're not *really* hungry; you're *bored*

Comment: You just lost your *appetite.*

Comment: @Jim Hunger and appetite are independent. Being hungry with no appetite is very common, esp., due to psychosomatic factors.

Comment: I'd consider something like hunger *malaise*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reference the beautiful word *ennui*;

en·nui
änˈwē/

**noun**
a feeling of listlessness and dissatisfaction arising from a lack of occupation or excitement.

*or*  Satisfaction by the Stones

☺

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this feeling arises when you're **thirsty** but you don't realize it.

If you feel both hungry and stuffed at the same time, you can say you're **queasy.**

A **picky eater** (or **finicky eater**) might not enjoy most foods even when hungry.

Also consider **sweet tooth** for someone who craves sugary foods or **food snob** for someone who only likes certain fancier foods.

Comment: Queasiness is a feeling of slight nausea.  That's definitely not hungry and stuffed at the same time-  it might be how feel you feel shortly *after* feeling hungry and stuffed, but I don't think anyone who is feeling queasy will say they also feel hungry.

Comment: The feeling I'm describing is definitely queasy, and also nauseous, but it's not the only type of queasy. I went many happy years without experiencing it, and if you're lucky, you've no idea what it feels like. The best way I can describe it is genuinely not knowing whether the eating a horse or eating nothing and throwing up will make the discomfort go away, or neither.

Comment: Ok, but that is not what OP is asking about. I believe OP is asking about the standard, I'm hungry but I don't know what I want- not pizza, not steak, not salad, not sushi...

Comment: @Jim I know exactly what Qaz means, in my case it's caused by low blood sugar, which would be cured by eating, yet you don't feel like eating. I believe it's similar to morning sickness - ask any woman who's experienced that and she'll tell you how you can be hungry and queasy at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [fussy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fussy),  [fastidious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fastidious) and *hard-to-please*  can convey the meaning:

> - Paying great or excessive attention to personal tastes and appearance; fastidious: *He was always fussy about food.*
> - excessively particular, critical, or demanding; hard to please: *a fastidious eater.*
> - requiring or characterized by excessive care or delicacy; painstaking.

Answer (score 0):

Anorexia
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
    Look up anorexia in Wiktionary, the free dictionary.

Anorexia may refer to:
Contents

```
1 Eating conditions
2 Relationships
3 Music
4 See also
```

Eating conditions

```
Anorexia (symptom), the symptom of poor appetite whatever the cause
Anorexia nervosa, an eating disorder of excessive weight loss and usually undue concern about body shape
Anorexia mirabilis, people who would starve themselves, sometimes to the death, for the sake of piety.
```

I think it could be a sign of anorexia.